# Is there a way to add ads to a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, ads

After hours of looking for an ad service like google ads, trying to add them to my new tab chrome extension, I couldn't find a single one that allows ads in the extension. All the services need a website URL to place their ads and extensions don't have URLs.
So, how can I put an ad on the extension?
Please help; any response is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put amazon affiliate links with banners

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal pls elaborate more?

Comment: @Volatil3 You can read about Amazon affiliates here: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/ and here is the page specifically for banners etc https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/promotion/buildlinks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create/using a website only for rendering ads and the put your chrome extension an iframe to show ads for your users.

Comment: How would one go about doing that?

Comment: put your ads script on html page and hosting anywhere you want for instance (heroku, s3) and then you call this page on iframe [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Comment: @EmersonJose will Chrome Ext allow it at the time of approval?